How do I access an array item by index in handlebars?
Here is my json.
{
  "data": [
    {
      "Category": "without",
      "Nb1": 12,
      "Nb3": 20,
      "percent": 66.67
    }
  ]
}

I would like to be able to write in html
Category without for Nb1 

but the value of Category and the name "Nb1" are not always the same name, instead of Nb1 and Nb3 it can be Nb4 and Nb10 so I cannot call the value by {{Nb1}}. I need to find a way to call it by index because the order doesn't change. So I want to call first the value associated with Category and then the name of the 'column' at index 1 (here "Nb1").
I tried this
<ul class="toc">
  {{#each data}}
    <li>{{this}}</li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>

and got [object Object]
Then I tried this
{{data.[0]}} 

and got nothing.
Finally I tried this
{{data.0}}


and got :
Parse error on line 1:
{{data.0}}
-------^
Expecting 'ID', got 'NUMBER'


Have you tried data[0] instead of accessing it as an object?

JavaScript object properties don't have indexes, and it is very unwise to rely on property name ordering.

I think you are using the wrong data structure. Instead of relying on the position of a key whose name can change - ie., is really a value - make that key a value, accessible at a fixed key - like { for: "Nb1" }.

Same kind of error for data[0]
Parse error on line 1:
{{data[0]}}
--^
Expecting 'ID', 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'BOOLEAN', 'UNDEFINED', 'NULL', 'DATA', got 'INVALID'

yes I think I will have no other choice than to change my structure

You probably need to access one of the properties in the object. Like this:
<ul class="toc">
  {{#each data}}
    <li>{{this.Category}}</li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>

Most frameworks are not able to render a whole object in an array (at least out of the box).
